# SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many Dynamic Set-like Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship -- I want this relationship to be set-like.

That is, the association table should not have duplicate values. I have a uniqueness constraint on the MySQL server to accomplish this.  The number of items in the relationship is large, so the relationship is configured as dynamic.

The problem is, I would still like to be able to use the built-in instrumentation to add items to the relationship. However, this results in "INSERT" statements being emitted for the relationship. I would prefer them to be "INSERT IGNORE" statements, since I don't want to have to load all of the items to determine whether or not they currently exist.

Has anybody ever dealt with this? Does anybody know of a way to ask SQLAlchemy to emit INSERT IGNORE statements for a dynamic relationship?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but it would seem to need a bit more use-case definition. `INSERT IGNORE` looks to be MySQL-specific, but a quick look doesn't turn up anything in the SA docs. Can you propose an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prefix_with()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.prefix_with) function, available in 0.7.7 version of SqlAlchemy.